# c++ nbody simulation passing array as reference

Tags: c++

I have a problem when trying to write a code to solve the nbody problem when using an array which contains all the bodies. My code doesn't do the right thing and i have no idea where it goes wrong though i suspect it has something to do with passing the array as a reference. To make it easier to spot my mistakes i will inculde a working version of the code which doesn't use the array containing all the bodies in the same way. The following is the code which doesn't work( when calculataing the orbit of a body you get a straight line instead of an ellipse with this code):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#define h  10000.0                  // size of the timestep
#define N  3                        // number of bodies
#define G  6.67384*pow(10.0,-11)    // gravitational constant

using namespace std;



class particle{
      public:
      double kx1,kx2,kx3,kx4, kv1, kv2, kv3, kv4;
      double ky1, ky2, ky3, ky4, kvy1, kvy2, kvy3, kvy4;
      double x,y,vx,vy,m;


      double dist(particle body){
             double dx = x - body.x;
             double dy = y - body.y;
             return sqrt(pow(dx,2.0)+pow(dy,2.0));
             }

      double g(double x1, double y1,particle body){
             return G*body.m*(body.x-x1)/pow(dist(body),3.0);
             }

      double p(double x1, double y1, particle body){
             return G*body.m*(body.y-y1)/pow(dist(body),3.0);
       }


      void update(){                                      //object advances 1 step
           x = x + (1/6.0)*(kx1+2*kx2+2*kx3+kx4);
           vx = vx + (1/6.0)*(kv1+2*kv2+2*kv3+kv4);
           y = y + (1/6.0)*(ky1+2*ky2+2*ky3+ky4);
           vy = vy + (1/6.0)*(kvy1+2*kvy2+2*kvy3+kvy4);
           }

     void create(double x1, double y1, double vx1, double vy1, double m1){  //choose the inital conditions for a new object
                      x = x1;
                      y = y1;
                      vx = vx1;
                      vy = vy1;
                      m =m1;
                      }

     bool operator ==(particle &other){
          if(x == other.x && y == other.y && vx == other.vx && vy == other.vy){
               return true;
               }
               }

      };




particle bodies[N];


void set(particle (&bodies)[N]){
     bodies[0].create(1, 1, -2, 1, 2*pow(10.0,30));
     bodies[1].create(2870671*pow(10.0,6), 0, 0, 6800, 8.6810*pow(10.0,25));
     bodies[2].create(4498542*pow(10.0,6),0 ,0, 5430, 1.0243*pow(10.0,26));
     }


double xforce(double x1, double y1, particle body, particle bodies[N]){    //force in the x- direction

       double fx = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
           if (bodies[i] == body ){;}

           else{
                fx += body.g(x1,y1,bodies[i]);
                }
                }
       return fx;
       }

double yforce(double x1, double y1, particle body, particle bodies[N]){ //force in the y- direction 

       double fy = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
           if (bodies[i] == body) {;}

           else{
                fy += body.p(x1,y1,bodies[i]);
                }
                }
       return fy;
       }


void corr(double t, particle bodies[N]){                            //runge kutta 4
     for(int i =0; i <= N; i++){

            bodies[i].kx1 = t*bodies[i].vx;
            bodies[i].kv1 = t*xforce(bodies[i].x, bodies[i].y, bodies[i], bodies);
            bodies[i].ky1 = t*bodies[i].vy;
            bodies[i].kvy1 = t*yforce(bodies[i].x, bodies[i].y, bodies[i], bodies);

            bodies[i].kx2 = t*(bodies[i].vx + 0.5*bodies[i].kv1);
            bodies[i].kv2 = t*xforce(bodies[i].x + 0.5*bodies[i].kx1, bodies[i].y + 0.5*bodies[i].ky1, bodies[i], bodies);
            bodies[i].ky2 = t*(bodies[i].vy + 0.5*bodies[i].kvy1);
            bodies[i].kvy2 = t*yforce(bodies[i].x + 0.5*bodies[i].kx1, bodies[i].y + 0.5*bodies[i].ky1, bodies[i], bodies);

            bodies[i].kx3 = t*(bodies[i].vx+ 0.5*bodies[i].kv2);
            bodies[i].kv3 = t*xforce(bodies[i].x + 0.5*bodies[i].kx2, bodies[i].y + 0.5*bodies[i].ky2, bodies[i], bodies);
            bodies[i].ky3 = t*(bodies[i].vy+ 0.5*bodies[i].kvy2);
            bodies[i].kvy3 = t*yforce(bodies[i].x + 0.5*bodies[i].kx2, bodies[i].y + 0.5*bodies[i].ky2,bodies[i], bodies);

            bodies[i].kx4 = t*(bodies[i].vx + bodies[i].kv3);
            bodies[i].kv4 = t*xforce(bodies[i].x+ bodies[i].kx3, bodies[i].y + bodies[i].ky3, bodies[i], bodies);
            bodies[i].ky4 = t*(bodies[i].vy + bodies[i].kvy3);
            bodies[i].kvy4 = t*yforce(bodies[i].x + bodies[i].kx3, bodies[i].y + bodies[i].ky3, bodies[i], bodies);
            }
     }


void calculate(particle (&bodies)[N]){
     set(bodies);
     ofstream file;
     file.open("tester.txt");
     for(int i =0; i <=50000; i++){

             corr(h, bodies);                          
             for(int j = 0; j <= N; j++){
                     bodies[j].update();
                     }                   
             if( i%1000 == 0){

                 file << i*h;
                 for(int j = 0; j <=N ; j++){
                          file <<"  "<<bodies[j].x << "  "<< bodies[j].y;
                          }
                 file <<"  "<<"\n";
                 }
             else{;}
             }
     file.close();
     }


int main()
{   
    calculate(bodies);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the working version of the code, both are supposed to solve the same problem:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#define h  10000.0
#define N  3
#define G  6.67384*pow(10.0,-11)

using namespace std;




class particle{
      public:
      double kx1,kx2,kx3,kx4, kv1, kv2, kv3, kv4;
      double ky1, ky2, ky3, ky4, kvy1, kvy2, kvy3, kvy4;
      double x,y,vx,vy,m;


      double dist(particle body){
             double dx = x - body.x;
             double dy = y - body.y;
             return sqrt(pow(dx,2.0)+pow(dy,2.0));
             }

      double g(double x1, double y1,particle body){
             return G*body.m*(body.x-x1)/pow(dist(body),3.0);
             }

      double p(double x1, double y1, particle body){
             return G*body.m*(body.y-y1)/pow(dist(body),3.0);
       }


      void update(){            
           x = x + (1/6.0)*(kx1+2*kx2+2*kx3+kx4);
           vx = vx + (1/6.0)*(kv1+2*kv2+2*kv3+kv4);
           y = y + (1/6.0)*(ky1+2*ky2+2*ky3+ky4);
           vy = vy + (1/6.0)*(kvy1+2*kvy2+2*kvy3+kvy4);
           }

     void create(double x1, double y1, double vx1, double vy1, double m1){
                      x = x1;
                      y = y1;
                      vx = vx1;
                      vy = vy1;
                      m =m1;
                      }

     bool operator ==(particle &other){
          if(x == other.x && y == other.y && vx == other.vx && vy == other.vy){
               return true;
               }
               }

     bool operator !=(particle &other){
          if(x != other.x || y != other.y || vx != other.vx || vy != other.vy){
               return true;
               }
               }
      };



particle zon, uranus, neptunus;
particle closest[] = {uranus, neptunus};



void set(){
     zon.create(1, 1, -2, 1, 2*pow(10.0,30));
     uranus.create(2870671*pow(10.0,6), 0, 0, 6800, 8.6810*pow(10.0,25));
     neptunus.create(4498542*pow(10.0,6),0 ,0, 5430, 1.0243*pow(10.0,26));
     }


double xforce(double x1, double y1, particle body){    

       particle bodies[] = {zon, uranus, neptunus};

       double fx = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           if (bodies[i] == body ){;}

           else{
                fx += body.g(x1,y1,bodies[i]);
                }
                }
       return fx;
       }

double yforce(double x1, double y1, particle body){ 

       particle bodies[] = {zon, uranus, neptunus};

       double fy = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
           if (bodies[i] == body) {;}

           else{
                fy += body.p(x1,y1,bodies[i]);
                }
                }
       return fy;
       }


void corr(particle& body, double t){
     body.kx1 = t*body.vx;
     body.kv1 = t*xforce(body.x, body.y, body);
     body.ky1 = t*body.vy;
     body.kvy1 = t*yforce(body.x, body.y, body);

     body.kx2 = t*(body.vx + 0.5*body.kv1);
     body.kv2 = t*xforce(body.x + 0.5*body.kx1, body.y + 0.5*body.ky1, body);
     body.ky2 = t*(body.vy + 0.5*body.kvy1);
     body.kvy2 = t*yforce(body.x + 0.5*body.kx1, body.y + 0.5*body.ky1, body);

     body.kx3 = t*(body.vx+ 0.5*body.kv2);
     body.kv3 = t*xforce(body.x + 0.5*body.kx2, body.y + 0.5*body.ky2, body);
     body.ky3 = t*(body.vy+ 0.5*body.kvy2);
     body.kvy3 = t*yforce(body.x + 0.5*body.kx2, body.y + 0.5*body.ky2,body);

     body.kx4 = t*(body.vx+body.kv3);
     body.kv4 = t*xforce(body.x+ body.kx3, body.y + body.ky3, body);
     body.ky4 = t*(body.vy + body.kvy3);
     body.kvy4 = t*yforce(body.x + body.kx3, body.y + body.ky3, body);
     }







void bereken(){
     set();
     ofstream file;
     file.open("tester.txt");
     for(int i =0; i <=50000; i++){
             corr(zon, h);
             corr(uranus, h);
             corr(neptunus, h);

             zon.update();
             uranus.update();
             neptunus.update();

             if( i%1000 == 0){             
                 file << i*h <<"  "<<zon.x << "  "<< zon.y <<"    "<<uranus.x<<"    " <<uranus.y <<"   "<< neptunus.x<<"  "<<neptunus.y<<"   "<<"\n";
                 }
             else{;}
             }
     file.close();
     }


int main()
{   
    bereken();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't just post hundreds of lines of code and expect us to "spot errors".  You should be using debugging techniques to narrow down the scope of the problem.

Comment: Define doesn't work.

Comment: The problems aren't something a debugger can find, everything compiles, but the first code does something wrong. Instead of an elliptic orbit you find straight lines when plotting the x and y coordinates of a body with the first code. I don't know exactly where the problem lies so i couldn't narrow it down further.

Comment: Work out the calculations on paper, and using your debugger, step through the code line-by-line and check the calculations give the correct result.

Comment: @user3642133 _"The problems aren't something a debugger can find ..."_ I seriously doubt that!!

Comment: Or atleast mine can't.

Comment: Test your functions one by one, then in combination, to narrow down where your problem is. Then use a debugger to trace the values if you can't figure it out. SO's not a debugging service.

Comment: Sorry if i posted an inappropriate question. I tried for more than two hours to find the problem and i couldn't so i came to SO. I'm not an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are overflowing your `bodies[]` array in 3 places:

```
#define N  3   
particle bodies[N];

for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    bodies[i].x = ...  // Oops, access bodies[3] which doesn't exist
```

The correct loop, which you do use in two places, is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  // 0 to < N
```

Comment: Thanks for the input i fixed that problem but the result remains the same. Something else must be wrong with the code